# Django: How To use SplitArrayField?

Tags: django, forms, postgresql

I am trying to test out SplitArrayField,

`class MYForm(forms.Form):
      places = SplitArrayField(forms.IntegerField(), size=4)`

Now, When I do: 
`form = MYForm({'places': [1,2,14,3]})`
`form.is_valid()` returns `False`
and `form.cleaned_data` is `{}`

I checked the official docs, cant find a example. please fix me.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/forms/#django.contrib.postgres.forms.SplitArrayField

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to pass data for a `SplitArrayField` is like this:

```
form = MYForm({
    'places_0': '1',
    'places_1': '2',
    'places_2': '14',
    'places_3': '3',
})
form.is_valid() # True
form.cleaned_data # {'places': [1, 2, 14, 3]}
```

The field names need to be "split", and an index needs to be appended. The general format of a field name is `'{field_name}_{index}'`.

If you were to use a `SimpleArrayField`, the input data would look like this instead:

```
class MYForm(forms.Form):
    places = SimpleArrayField(forms.IntegerField())

form = MYForm({
    'places': '1,2,14,3'
})
form.is_valid() # True
form.cleaned_data # {'places': [1, 2, 14, 3]}
```